# how would you create the sound of someone (in shoes) stepping through a puddle?

Tags: water

Is there something that would be more effective for this sound than the actual thing?

I will also try slapping shoes in water by hand.
Would a more fizzy or viscous liquid give a more detailed and longer sound?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I will have to perform this indoors, during 30-second recording, with no option to edit it afterwards - I will have one shot to get the sound right, so I'll practice before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the surface. With dirt/mud, I would add the puddle after the fact by building a pool surrounded by dirt with mud and the correct water depth. Also, I sometimes just use my hand to create the splash and have a slight squish sound with footsteps to highlight the surface. If it is cement, find a cement surface that has an indentation so that you can trap water stepping into the trap while still doing the feet on a cement surface. With grass, I use military camouflage for green grass and 1/4 inch tape for dry grass. Here, I would also add in the puddles after the main feet track is done. For hard dirt, dig an indentation into the dirt and then fill it will the desired depth.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

What's the ground material? How deep are the puddles? What's the walking speed? What kind of shoes?

Comment: The puddle is on concrete. It is shallow. Jogging speed. Heavy shoes.

Answer (score 1):

A saturated chamois cloth can be used if you are pushed for time, but the best approach is real shoes and real water.

Answer (score 0):

Also, what do YOU want to hear when you think of stepping in a puddle? Do you want a thick, gushy sound of water soaking into the shoe? Do you want a soppy splash? Do you want the classic 'plop' sound?

Comment: Hmm, a quick sound, just a 'splish' (surface splash), but not a plop.

Answer (score 0):

Me, I would bring me a mic, my recorder, my boom, a fitting pair of boots or shoes, and an at least 2l bottle of water or two (if sunshine and no natural puddles) and just go nuts. Anything I couldn't perform in this makeshift puddle would be sweetened afterwards. Though I'd try and get as much of what I need as possibly already in the field.

Comment: Good idea. Will have to do it indoors in just one take though.